How to use Python Multiprocessing with Undefined Queue.task_done()
I have the following script for which I want to speed up the processing by splitting the task across cpu cores.
myscript.py
from queue import Queue
from worker_script import Worker
    
task_queue = Queue(maxsize=1)

while some_other_functions:
    task_queue.put(Some_Stuff)          ## Step happens randomly anytime. 
                                        ## Hence number of input tasks cannot be known

Worker(task_queue).start()

task_queue.join()

## further script that needs the above task_queue to be successfully completed first

worker_script.py
class Worker:

    def __init__(self, task_queue):
        self.task_queue = task_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:

            task_object = self.task_queue.get()
            
            do_some_big_calculation(task_object)       #### The Step I want to use Multiprocess

            self.task_queue.task_done()

If i were to apply multiprocessing to do_some_big_calculation(task_object), how would I apply the task_done() method to task_queue?
I am applying task_done() so that the task_queue.join() blocker knows that all Tasks assigned have been completed.
My Implementation in the worker_script.py is:
import multiprocessing

class Worker:

    def __init__(self, task_queue):
        self.task_queue = task_queue

    def run(self):
        num_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 2
        jobs = []
        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processes) as pool:
            while True:
                new_job = pool.apply_async(self.sub_worker)
                jobs.append(new_job)

    def sub_worker(self):
        while True:

            task_object = self.task_queue.get()
            
            do_some_big_calculation(task_object)       #### The Step I want to use Multiprocess

            self.task_queue.task_done()

I am relying on the .get() to block the multiprocessing until another task becomes available.
My modified implementation however gets stuck somewhere that I am not being able to figure out.
Any help on my implementation or a completely new solution is appreciated!
Thank you!

You say that you "get stuck somewhere" but you haven't posted a minimal, reproducible example, so it becomes very difficult to determine where and why you get stuck (whatever getting stuck means).
I do notice that your run method has an infinite loop submitting "jobs" and so the program will never complete. At some point run has to to decide to terminate and then it could issue a call to task_queue.join() to await all tasks being completed. But if you want to use a call to method task_done on self.task_queue, then self.task_queue must  be an instance of multiprocessing.JoinableQueue, which it isn't. You also call non-existent start method on a Worker instance.
You do not need to use a multiprocesssing.JoinableQueue instance at all since a multiprocessing.pool Pool instance has its own internal queues for submitting jobs and receiving results. You code should look more like:
worker_script.py
import multiprocessing

class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
        # Why multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 2?
        num_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 2
        self._pool = Pool(num_processes)

    def submit_task(self, task_object):
        # Node need to save returned AsyncResult instance unless you need a
        # return value from sub_worker:
        self.pool.apply_async(self.sub_worker, args=(task_object,))
        
    def terminate(self):
        """Wait for all submitted tasks to complete."""
        self._pool.close()
        self._pool.join()
    
    def sub_worker(self, task_object):
        do_some_big_calculation(task_object)

myscript.py
def main():
    worker = Worker()

    while some_other_functions:
        worker.submit_task(task_object)
        
    # Wait for all submitted tasks to complete:
    worker.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Update
The following uses a multiprocessing.JoinableQueue instance along with daemon multiprocessing.Process instances:
worker_script.py
import multiprocessing

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, task_queue: multiprocessing.JoinableQueue):
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        
    def run(self):
        # Why multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 2?
        num_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 2
        for _ in range(num_processes):
            # These need to be daemon processes:
            multiprocessing.Process(target=self.sub_worker, daemon=True).start()

    def sub_worker(self):
        while True:
            task_object = self.task_queue.get()
            do_some_big_calculation(task_object)
            self.task_queue.task_done()

myscript.py
import multiprocessing

from worker_script import Worker

def main():
    task_queue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    worker = Worker(task_queue)
    worker.run()

    while some_other_functions:
        task_queue.put(task_object)
        
    # Wait for all submitted tasks to complete:
    task_queue.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Thanks for your input!
The .start() method triggers the Worker Thread's activity.
Is there any way to implement the above solution while using task_queue as a queue.Queue object? Since other functions depend on it. Hence I need to used the task_queue.task_done() method to unblock the task_queue.join()

You are multiprocessing and not multithreading. Therefore, you cannot use a queue.Queue object nor a multiprocessing.Queue object, which does not support a task_done method. You need to use a multiprocessing.JoinableQueue object. I will post an update.
